# How to change my route path from database?

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.3

I have `BlogController` that has multi actions in it. I want to be able to change my route path to another from my database. Suppose I want to change the word `blog` to `news` in my database.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog_list") BEFORE CHANGE
     * @Route("/news", name="blog_list") AFTER CHANGE
     */
    public function list()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

it is possible?

Comment: Read [How to Create a custom Route Loader](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html)